# LUIS batch testing

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I want to batch train my Luis app. My JSON file for batch testing.

```
[
    {
        "text": "Wo ist die CMS?",
        "intent": "standort",
        "entities":
        [
            {
                "entity": "place",
                "startPos": 9,
                "endPos": 11
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I click run, the running icon is there, but nothing happens, even after 5 Minutes. What am I doing wrong? When i run the example file from the LUIS page everything is fine. Example from MS:

```
 [
    {
        "text": "hey dad, are you hungry?",
        "intent": "None",
        "entities":
        [
            {
                "entity": "FamilyMember",
                "startPos": 4,
                "endPos": 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Open F12/dev tools and see what is going on. Perhaps post any console errors or network tab returned JSON.

Comment: Error message in dev tools is
code:"BadArgument" 
"message": "Character indicies 9,11 do not correspond to the start and end of a token."

Comment: A token is a word. You can't begin or end on a space between words.

Comment: @Louicha, DFBerry's correct. Your token for your language must be a word, but you have a space between indices 9 and 11 in the utterance "Wo ist die CMS?", meaning you're saying "e C" is a token/word, resulting in errors in your dev tools. Just changing the "startPos" and "endPos" to be the start and end of a word should resolve the error:
[
    {
        "text": "Wo ist die CMS?",
        "intent": "standort",
        "entities":
        [
            {
                "entity": "place",
                "startPos": 11,
                "endPos": 13
            }
        ]
    }
]

Comment: @Zeryth So I have to count the blanks? Because in the example it looks as if these were not counted.

Comment: @Louicha, correct, spaces count when you're counting indices in a string.

Comment: In the example given, "hey dad, are you hungry?" character(index): h(0), e(1), y(2), " "(3), d(4), a(5), d(6) -- spaces are actually counted as you see "startPost": 4 and "endPost": 6